# NullPointerException on Running

Tags: blackberry

I have been working with the streaming media start to finish project,which i got from

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Streaming-media-Start-to-finish/ta-p/488255 ...

the project has been working fine till i put in a Playcontrol it worked but when i click on play it gives an error,i had to clean the simulator because it gave me this error i.e

Error inside JVM: Access violation reading from 0x0000000C. 
On fixing that by cleaning the simulator i ran the streaming media code and it complied perfectly but when i click on the app itself it gives a NullPointerException.
Could this be from the PlayerClass i implemented CustomButtons or from the simulator itself? i can post the PlayerClass Code here if anyone offers to assist

Please i need help!
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: thanks alot for the immediate responce but i have fixed it

Comment: it is still giving me the error, i tried posting my code but it too long?